# If two sibling inline elements are marked with vertical-align, what's the font serving as baseline?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

As I understand it, `vertical-align` aligns **inline-block** elements with respect to the **baseline** of text font. This  makes sense when there's a text sibling to the **inline-block** element so that we know what's the font size to serve as **baseline**.

But what if the sibling is not text, and is instead another **inline-block** element? What's the text font whose **baseline** is taken?

For example:

```html
<div style="padding: 8px 16px; background-color: green">
    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;vertical-align:text-top">Hello</div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:72px;vertical-align:text-top">Help</div>
</div>
```

The output is:
[image]

What exactly is happening here? What's the baseline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#strut):

> The following values only have meaning with respect to a parent inline element, **or to the strut of a parent block container element.**

And

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. **We call that imaginary box a "strut."** (The name is inspired by TeX.).

So it's like we always have a *kind* of text having 0 width inside our container that will define the baseline.

```css
.box {
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) 0 22px/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.box > * {
  outline:1px solid;
}
```

```html
With text
<div style="padding: 8px 16px; background-color: green" class="box">
     BASELINE
    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;vertical-align:text-top">Hello</div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:72px;vertical-align:text-top">Help</div>
</div>
without text (the reference is the same)
<div style="padding: 8px 16px; background-color: green" class="box">
    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:18px;vertical-align:text-top">Hello</div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;font-size:72px;vertical-align:text-top">Help</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This explains the placement of the "Hello" text. But why is "Help" aligned below the baseline? It should have been also aligned below the ascenders of "BASELINE" just like "Hello", no?

Comment: @Daud both are aligned at *text-top* which means: *Align the top of the box with the top of the parent's content area* So the top of both elements are aligned width the top of the content area defined by the text inside the parent (or the strut). Check how the top of both inline-block are in the same position which is the top of the parent's content area

Comment: @Daud to better illustrate check this: https://jsfiddle.net/m8b9taLp/ I added a coloration around the text so you can better see the top of the content area

Comment: Thanks you so much. Its much clearer now. One thing I couldn't understand is the purpose of the red line with the vertical position set to "22px/100%"

Comment: @Daud I wanted to illustrate the baseline in both cases to show that it's the same with and without text because even without text we have the strut that will define that baseline